# Upgrade .net 3.5 , MVC 1 project to .net4.5 and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have VS2008 solution in which I have web MVC1 project and target framework is 3.5.
Now I want upgrade solution to VS2013 and upgrade this project to .net 4.5 framework and MVC 5.

Any suggestion. Is it possible to do it? How to proceed?

Comment: You are using MVC 1? the proof of concept from 2009? Pretty positive you'd have to go from 1 to 2, then 2 to 4, then 4 to 5

Comment: Currently it is MVC1

Comment: right, so there is no way to go directly from 1 to 5, as I stated in my earlier comment, 1 to 2 first, fix all the errors, references, etc.; once you have a working project again, then upgrade from 2 to 4, fix the project up; finally go from 4 to 5.

Comment: Can you please explain why 1 to 2 , then 2 to 4 then 5.. why not 1 to 3 ,then3 to 5? Any specific reason?

Comment: I wasn't aware of a solution to go from 1 to 3, but if there is, that would probably work fine.

Comment: What about setting up a new blank MVC5 project and then adding your controllers and views from the MVC1 project and updating them when necessary?

Comment: It is huge project having 8000+views and controller. So practically not possible. So is there any way to upgrade it with out doing that.

Comment: I think this is one of those situations where the upgrade path is going to be extremely long and potentially painful since the base framework is so out of date (4 versions and 6 years).  Either start with a fresh project and move your components over or upgrade the project 3 times (1->2->4->5) as stated above.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tommy this is near impossible to jump from 1 to 5. You are going to have to follow the upgrade path suggested by the guys above. Perhaps a lesson to take to your managers for future, dedicating 1-2 days per year to upgrade /recompile with latest versions will save many headaches 6 years down the line... never mind the security updates in that time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been already said in the "Alundra the dreamwalker" comment, in ASP .NET MVC 5 there are many new features to which you should be careful, above all, in order to avoid their loss.

Said this, you have only two choises:

1) Create a new ASP .NET MVC 5 web application and bring inside all the code. (this requires the knowledge of the structure and the content of the default template)

2) Change manually all assembly files and all config files, passing by each major release.

If you are interested to this path, I found some articles over www.asp.net.

- Upgrade MVC 1 to MVC 2

  http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes
- Upgrade MVC 2 to MVC 3

  http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading
- Upgrade MVC 3 to MVC 4

  http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806
- Upgrade MVC 4 to MVC 5

  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I Suggest you to evaluate the time of both operations.

In any case, make a backup of your solution, and start working on VS2013.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of major updates/upgrades between `MVC1` and `MVC5`
Over the years , MS redesigned a lot of main components, functionality and implemented new Technologies to accommodate the fast changing world of the web in particular. To give an idea , here's a non-exhaustive list of changes from MVC1 to MVC5

**Syntax**

- (`HTML Syntax`) Web Forms view engine syntax: <%=Html code %> in
  MVC1 and 2.
- (`Razor Syntax`) Razor View Engine syntax: @Html code in MVC3 and
  plus.

**Layout Support :**

- Supports not only Master Page but also Layout Page in MVC 3 (and newer versions)

Starting `MVC2` until `MVC5` here's list of *"Important"* new features:

- Areas Support
- Client-side validation
- DataAnnotation Validation Support
- Strongly Typed UI Helpers
- Enhanced support for dependency injection
- Support for output caching
- Bundling and Minification
- Enabling Logins from Facebook and Other Sites Using OAuth and OpenID
- Database Migrations
- Filters
- Attribute Routing
- ASP.NET Identity
- ...

So my recommendation is to start a new project in `MVC5` and try to refactor as much as possible from your `MVC1` project, as there is no way to just *"Upgrade"* your existing project.

**References:**  [Reference1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released)  [Reference2](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/XWX7210713-A-brief-history-of-Asp.Net-MVC-framework.html)